# Restructure Mysql query result in multiple table columns with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

The weather data on my website, e.g. temperature, needs to be displayed for the various weeks of the year, for the last three years in a HTML table.

Is there a way to restructure my query result (resort, year, wk, temp) in a format where I have the week numbers in the rows and in the columns the last three years (3 columns)

Column(s) of the database table:

- res_id
- resort
- yr
- wk
- temp

output needs to be like this

1. resort, wk, 2012, 2011, 2010
2. adelboden, 1, -23, -12, -15
3. adelboden, 2, -18, -19, -2
4. adelboden, 3, -16, -18, -11

on request the code, but this makes little sense

```
$nI = 1;
while ($one = mysql_fetch_assoc($rQuery101) and $two = mysql_fetch_assoc($rQuery802))
{
if ($nI == 6)
{
                echo '</tr>';
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>2012</td>';
                echo '<td>2011</td>';
                echo '<td>2011</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
                echo '<tr>';
}
echo '<td>';
echo $one['temp1'];
echo ' <b>(';
echo $two['temp2'];
echo ')</b></td>';
$nI++;
}

                echo '</tr>';
                echo '</table>';
        }
```

Comment: Column(s):  res_id
resort
yr
wk

Comment: Another thing - can you please add how the output will look alike? (In order to make sure I understood your question)

Comment: Please edit the "output required", because it is hard to understand.

Comment: sorry, I have a bit of difficulty lay-outing the last bit of the post. Don't downgrade me please!

Comment: Please add code. Can't improve what we can't see.

Answer (score 0):

seems to me you'll want to have an array representing each resort/week pair and then populate it from the query results. otherwise you'll just end up with an unnecessarily complex query.

Comment: your query is going to return data for one of the years and yes, you're right that your php code will then have to find the right place to put it. my point is that the query itself won't do that, the php code will do that. your query probably doesn't need to be restructured, as your question was asking.